# How to set ticks on Fixed Position , matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Can anyone help me set the ticks on a fixed position using matplotlib? I've tried using FixedPosition as this tutorial describes:

```
ax = pl.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(eval(locator))
```

http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/matplotlib/matplotlib.html#figures-subplots-axes-and-ticks

But when I try to run, it tells me that set_major_locator method does not exist.

A simple example would be very useful.

Thanks.

Comment: That link is a confusing out of context. The use of `eval` might be very clever for generating their example figures, it is very unclear what the value of `locator` is.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Just use `ax.set_xticks(positions)` or `ax.set_yticks(positions)`.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xticks([0.15, 0.68, 0.97])
ax.set_yticks([0.2, 0.55, 0.76])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this method will erase the existing ticks i have on plots. What if I want to add these additional ticks without affecting existing ones?

Comment: @dnth: You can `twinx()` or `twiny()` the chart to create a new axis with the ticks on the opposite side.

Comment: @dnth You can get the locations with `locs = ax.xaxis.get_ticklocs()`, modify that list to add the ticks you want, then follow Joe's suggestions with, `ax.set_xticks(locs)`.

Answer (score 15):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

name_list = ('Omar', 'Serguey', 'Max', 'Zhou', 'Abidin')
value_list = np.random.randint(0, 99, size = len(name_list))
pos_list = np.arange(len(name_list))

ax = plt.axes()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator((pos_list)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter((name_list)))
plt.bar(pos_list, value_list, color = '.75', align = 'center')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: That was helpful.

Comment: I would give five upvotes to this answer if I could. It was really helpful. If anyone looking for an explanation, set_major_locator() method sets the location of ticks in the graphics as per the list pos_list and also sets the tick labels according to pos_list. Now to get back the old tick labels, set_major_formatter() is being used.