# xtick max value setup with panda and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

How is it possible that the last xtick would be the last value of the data?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = [583, 1379, 1404, 5442, 5512, 5976, 5992, 6111, 6239, 6375, 6793, 6994, 7109, 7149, 7210, 7225, 7459, 8574, 9154, 9417, 9894, 10119, 10355, 10527, 11933, 12170, 12172, 12273, 12870, 13215, 13317, 13618, 13632, 13790, 14260, 14282, 14726, 15156, 19262, 21501, 21544, 21547, 21818, 21939, 22386, 22622, 22830, 23898, 25796, 26126, 26340, 28585, 28645, 28797, 28808, 28878, 29167, 29168, 31161, 31225, 32284, 32332, 32641, 33227, 34175, 34349, 34675, 34772, 34935, 35086]

d = pd.DataFrame(a)
d.hist(bins=50)
f = plt.figure()
plt.xlabel("xTEST")
plt.ylabel("yTEST")
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=.25, left=.25)

plt.ticklabel_format(style = 'plain')

plt.title('Title here!', color='black')
plt.xlim(xmin=1, xmax=35086)
plt.show()
```

Comment: How is it possible to set the last xtick to 35086 instead of 35000?

Comment: related question: [How to set ticks on Fixed Position , matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17129947/832621)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the same figure created by `pandas` you cannot create a new one (see below). You can set the ticks positions manually adding `plt.xticks()` after the `plt.xlim()`

```
plt.xticks(seq)
```

where the sequence `seq` can be `pd.np.linspace(1, 35086, 5)` for example, or given manually like:

```
seq = [1, 10000, 20000, 35086]
```

The final code would be:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = [583, 1379, 1404, 5442, 5512, 5976, 5992, 6111, 6239, 6375, 6793, 6994, 7109, 7149, 7210, 7225, 7459, 8574, 9154, 9417, 9894, 10119, 10355, 10527, 11933, 12170, 12172, 12273, 12870, 13215, 13317, 13618, 13632, 13790, 14260, 14282, 14726, 15156, 19262, 21501, 21544, 21547, 21818, 21939, 22386, 22622, 22830, 23898, 25796, 26126, 26340, 28585, 28645, 28797, 28808, 28878, 29167, 29168, 31161, 31225, 32284, 32332, 32641, 33227, 34175, 34349, 34675, 34772, 34935, 35086]

d = pd.DataFrame(a)
d.hist(bins=50)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlabel("xTEST")
ax.set_ylabel("yTEST")
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=.25, left=.25)
plt.ticklabel_format(style = 'plain')

ax.set_title('Title here!', color='black')
ax.set_xlim(xmin=1, xmax=35086)
ax.set_xticks(pd.np.linspace(1, 35086, 5))
plt.show()
```

Giving:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly what you need, but you'll need to delete the line

```
f = plt.figure()
```

if you want you histogram of `d` and the title/label/xlim etc. to be in the same chart.

Comment: Thank you, but now the last xtick is 35000 instead of 35086. Is it a way to set it to 35086?