# How to make xticklabel only the points of data list?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am creating a python application to show a Gantt chart of data `list`. But when I run the application I get this -->

[image]

Actually, I need the xticklabels should only be the points in the `data` list at the same end point from the graph. Something similar to this--> (sorry for the poor picture edit)

[image]

This what I have done so far:

```
self.f = Figure(figsize=(10, 8), dpi=100)
self.ax = self.f.add_subplot(2,1,2)

ind = numpy.arange(1)  # the x locations for the groups
width = .95

data = [2,4,5,7,8,12,16]

patch_handles = []

left = 1

for i, d in enumerate(data):
    patch_handles.append(self.ax.barh(ind, d, align='center', left=left, yerr=0.4, color='y'))
    left += d

for j in range(len(patch_handles)):
    for i, patch in enumerate(patch_handles[j].get_children()):
        bl = patch.get_xy()
        x = 0.5 * patch.get_width() + bl[0]
        y = 0.5 * patch.get_height() + bl[1]
        self.ax.text(x, y, "dd", ha='center')

self.ax.set_yticks(ind)
self.ax.set_yticklabels("G")
self.ax.set_xticklabels(data)
self.ax.set_xlabel('Scores')

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

**EDIT:** Screenshot after changing the codes from @scroopy noopers's the answer

[image]

Comment: Looks like you need to take the gap between the last bold vertical line and the side of the enclosing rectangle into account.

Comment: Well. Even without the vertical line, I can see the point '16' at the same position in the picture (Question's Edit section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set_xticks` to set the *positions* of the `xticks` (in addition to using `set_xticklabels` to set the values displayed at the tick positions):

```
self.ax.set_yticks(ind)
self.ax.set_yticklabels("G")
self.ax.set_xticks(numpy.cumsum(data))  # Set positions correctly
self.ax.set_xticklabels(data)
self.ax.set_xlabel('Scores')
```

Answer inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17130203/8951763).

---

**EDIT:** As the OP commented below, this resulted in an off-by-one misalignment for their specific plot. They were able to fix the misalignment with the simple tweak:

```
self.ax.set_xticks(numpy.cumsum(data) + 1)
```

Comment: I am getting the points of the data list, but it's not at the exact point. I will update the screenshot in the question.

Comment: I found the answer from his code:

I just need to update --> `self.ax.set_xticks(numpy.cumsum(data) + 1)`