# ticker.FixedFormatter strategy to show the tics of the ax2 axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

Given 3 arrays:

`X1 = 10.00, 30.10, 50.20, 70.30 ...`

`X2 = 1.9976433815311, 2.0109630315475, 2.0372702369401, 2.0665284897891 ...`

`Y  = -0.0000008764356, -0.0000149459573, -0.0000326996870, -0.0000513717121 ...`

There is a one-to-one correspondence between `X1`, `X2` and `Y`, i.e.

the i-th element of `X1` has an i-th associated value of `X2` and a i-th value of `Y`.

The following is the plot of `Y` as a function of `X1` (blue dots).

- I would need the `X2` axis to show all the corresponding `X2` values for each `X1` value.

Following the [second answer on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129947/how-to-set-ticks-on-fixed-position-matplotlib),

I have partially accomplished this thorugh the `ticker.FixedFormatter` strategy,
by which: the `X2` array needs to be transformed to a tuple, and each element of this tuple needs to be a string.

As can be seen, not all red values of `X2` are displayed for each value of `X1`, e.g. for `X1 = 10.0` the corresponding `X2 = 2.00` appears to be displaced.

I do not understand very well why this is occurring. I would appreciate if you could help me.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import sys

X1 = np.array([10.0000000000000, 30.1000000000000, 50.2000000000000, 70.3000000000000, 90.4000000000000, 110.5100000000000, 130.6100000000000, 150.7100000000000, 170.8100000000000, 190.9100000000000, 211.0100000000000, 231.1100000000000, 251.2100000000000, 271.3100000000000, 291.4100000000000, 311.5200000000000, 331.6200000000000 ])

Y = np.array([-0.0000008764356, -0.0000149459573, -0.0000326996870, -0.0000513717121, -0.0000652350399, -0.0000842214902, -0.0001003825474, -0.0001214363281, -0.0001376971422, -0.0001572720132, -0.0001971891337, -0.0002203926200, -0.0002747064193, -0.0003217228112, -0.0003764577474, -0.0004657478828, -0.0006232016207])

X2 = np.array([1.9976433815311, 2.0109630315475, 2.0372702369401, 2.0665284897891, 2.0995743328944, 2.1392386324550, 2.1789200955649, 2.2290243968267, 2.2872281293691, 2.3180577547912, 2.4100643103912, 2.4826981368480, 2.5794602952095, 2.6764219232389, 2.7963983991814, 2.9740753305878, 3.3107035136072])


##### Plotting:
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(X1, Y, linestyle='--', marker="o",  markersize=6, color='blue')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y', fontsize=20)

# Make the ax1-ticks and ax1-tick-labels match the line color (blue):
ax1.set_xlabel('X1', fontsize=20, color='blue')
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), rotation='45') # rotate them

# Create a new axis:
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

# Make the ax2-ticks and ax2-tick-labels match the red color: 
ax2.set_xlabel('X2', fontsize=20, color='red')
ax2.tick_params('x', colors='red')

fig.tight_layout()
ax2.set_xlim(1.9, 3.4)
ax1.set_ylim(-0.0007, 1.1e-5)
ax2.set_ylim(-0.0007, 1.1e-5)
ax1.grid()

# Convert all X2 elements to a list of strings:
X2_string_all = []
for i in X2:
  aux = "%.2f" % i
  X2_string = str(aux)
  X2_string_all.append(X2_string)

# Convert that list into a tuple:
X2_string_all_tuple = tuple(X2_string_all)

ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator((X1)))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter((X2_string_all_tuple)))

plt.show()
```

Something like this would be the desired plot (the red lines that come across the plot are not necessary):

[image]

Comment: So how would the upper axis know where to display a certain value such that you would be happy with it?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you very much for your efforts on trying to understand this problem and I do apologise for the confusion caused. Please find updated a figure showing how the upper `ax2` should look like

Comment: This comment was rather meant for you to think about how the upper axis could possibly be aware of your request of linking it to the lower axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `ax2` does not know that it should behave exactly as `ax1`, just with different labels. So you need to tell it,

```
ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
```

Then just use the same tick locations for both axes,

```
ax1.set_xticks(X1)
ax2.set_xticks(X1)
```

and label the ticks of `ax2` with values from `X2`

```
ax2.set_xticklabels(["%.2f" % i for i in X2])
```

Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X1 = np.array([10., 30.1, 50.2, 70.3, 90.4, 110.510, 130.610, 150.710, 170.810, 
               190.910, 211.010, 231.110, 251.210, 271.310, 291.410, 311.52, 331.62])

Y = np.array([-0.00000087, -0.0000149, -0.0000326, -0.0000513, -0.00006523, -0.0000842,
              -0.0001003, -0.0001214,  -0.00013769, -0.0001572, -0.0001971, -0.0002203, 
              -0.00027470, -0.0003217, -0.0003764, -0.0004657,  -0.00062320])

X2 = np.array([1.997, 2.0109, 2.0372, 2.0665, 2.099, 2.1392, 2.1789, 2.2290, 
               2.287, 2.3180, 2.4100, 2.4826, 2.579, 2.6764, 2.7963, 2.9740, 3.310])

##### Plotting:
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.grid()
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

ax1.plot(X1, Y, linestyle='--', marker="o",  markersize=6, color='blue')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y', fontsize=20)
ax1.set_xlabel('X1', fontsize=20, color='blue')
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), rotation='45') # rotate them 
ax2.set_xlabel('X2', fontsize=20, color='red')
plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), rotation='45', color='red')

# Set xlimits of ax2 the same as ax1
ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
# Set ticks at desired position
ax1.set_xticks(X1)
ax2.set_xticks(X1)
# Label ticks of ax2 with values from X2
ax2.set_xticklabels(["%.2f" % i for i in X2])

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. All these challenges mean a huge learning for me, through stepping stones, I'm afraid. I was aware of the existence of `set_xlim` but on the contrary, I didn't know the existence of `get_xlim`, thus this was the missing stepping stone. Thanks again