# To change values across x & y axis in a plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-science, x-axis

I want to change values across the x- & y-axes in a plot.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,DataFrame

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams

rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 7,6

x = range(1,20)
y = list(np.random.rand(19) * 100)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.01,0.1,1,1])
ax.plot(x,y,marker = 'o')
```

[image]

I want to change x-axis values that are appearing as decimals. Instead, I want to customize it and show values like 2,4,6 .. 18.

Any suggestions will be a kind help.
Thank you

Comment: You mean, you want to set the x-tick labels at specific positions like [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17130203/8881141)?

Comment: How to set this in a dataframe ?

Comment: Somehow, I was able to fix this problem.

mat.plot(grid = True, xticks = list(range(0,721,90)))